# merging branches in after many wrong commits

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to .git and I am using it with Sourcetree/Bitbucket. I don't need to share my code for the moment but only to keep track of my projects and allow me to undo or revert back to an old version.
I have read many guides but it's still a bit cryptic to me.

The way I want to use it is to create a branch from the master every time I need to add a new feature. I'd like to keep committing on that branch, and when it will be eventually working I would like to merge it back to the master, and then go on with the next feature.
Maybe there's even a better way to use it, I am open to suggestions.

I ended up in this situation, because I had to release quickly a new version and I didn't have the time to fix the repository. Late attempt to fix it resulted in even more mess. Maybe it's time to ask for help ;)
[image: SourceTree screnshot]

This is what I was supposed to do:
- on 29 gen, I wanted to create a new branch "transmitter_fo_nrf24l01+"
- keep committing on that branch until 5 feb
- on 6 feb, create a new branch (from master) "added_serial_interface" (I think I failed here somehow). 
- merge with master again with the version of 12 feb.
- create a new branch (from master) for a new feature

Today I could not merge added_serial_interface to master because of a conflict with the README file added on 5 feb, and the last attempts resulted in that lonely head...

How can I merge everything in the master branch now? I could not resolve the conflict.
I don't care too much about fixing all the history, but I'd like at least to start "clean" with the new feature now, and understand what my mistakes were.
Thanks!

PS sorry for the small pic, if you zoom in with the browser you can see it real size

Comment: If you want to get really serious about this, I suggest you take a look at Git-flow, which is a model for working with releases and feature branches. See the descriptions here (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and here (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: Thank you, clear and inspiring readings (especially the first one). I'm still a beginner but it becomes more and more useful as the projects grow.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're going to make changes to your process anyway, I recommend to adopt one of the proven approaches, e.g. Git-flow. It works well, has tooling and lots of support information. There are some other (similar) approaches mentioned on the Atlassian page (see link above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having separate branches for different features you are working on is a good practice. Things only get complicated if you are editing the same file independently in parallel branches (in your case *README* in the *master* as in the *added_serial_interface*). If you need to work on the same files, separate branches can make things difficult. Git usually merges automatically but with the same file edited in different branches you will have to do some manual merging.

In general I would avoid editing the same file in different branches. If you have to, try to first merge the changes of the first branch into the second branch and only after that make changes to that file in the second branch. (You had changed the README in the *master*. If you merge that change from the *master* into your other branch before you edit the README there the merges will work without conflicts)

To recover in your case you need to do some manual merging. Depending on your OS there are tools that help you to merge by displaying the two conflicting versions of the file by displaying them side by side and highlighting differences. (Maybe the git client you are using already has that build in). After manually editing the file to the final version you want you have to commit it to complete the merge. 
You can also simply tell git to use the version of one of the branches and ignore the other changes.

Have a look at the Git documentation: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge ("HOW TO RESOLVE CONFLICTS" and "MERGE STRATEGIES"). It looks complicated at first but learning git is definitely worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks, at the end I did it by changing the README in the master commit. I need to study a bit more ;)